# Ubuntu 15.10: Mouse stops working after pressing middle mouse button

Tags: usb

my usb mouse stops working after pressing the middle mouse button. It doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it works fine, sometimes the mouse freezes for a few seconds and starts working again, but more often than not, it stops working completely.

The only sure way to get it working again is rebooting, but sometimes switching USB ports works too (but not all the time). I've tried using different mice, but that doesn't seem to make a difference (i've tested with a cheap usb wired mouse and a logitech wireless usb mouse).

Somebody has any ideas how i at least could debug this?

Comment: Check for mentions of `USB` and/or `Mouse` in `dmesg -T` (time-of-day should correlate with the failure time) and in `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! "Thanks" and "Thanks in advance" are better  expressed with upvotes when you have enough privileges, hence saying thanks in the post only generate noise. Don't feel offended or think there's any problem if someone edited your post to remove a "Thank you".